# working with geoserver in flutter map. how to get map size x and y for the geoserver getfeatureinfo api

Tags: geoserver, fluttermap, getfeatureinfo

here is my code

```
            FlutterMap(
                  mapController: mapController,
                  options: MapOptions(
                    controller: mapController,
                    center: LatLng(33.680088056393814, 72.7987044426807),
                    zoom: 14,
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    onTap: (p, k) {
                      final bounds = mapController.bounds;
                      var a = mapController;
                      var sw = epsg3413CRS.projection.project(bounds.southWest!);
                      var ne = epsg3413CRS.projection.project(bounds.northEast!);
                      print('Map bounds:sw.x:  ${sw.x},${sw.y},${ne.x},${ne.y}');

                    },
                  ),
                  layers: layerz,
                ),
```

i have search alot but after too much effort i only got BBOX for api. but other parameters are remaining x, y, height, width etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.